# Bind objects in list with multiple forms

Tags: data-binding, qooxdoo

Here is my problem:

I have a list containing objects which are instances of different classes.
I would like to bind these objects to specific forms, depending on their class, when they are selected in the list. What is the best approach?

Here is [a code snippet](http://tinyurl.com/ntskqg8) of what I tried. Unfortunately, variable names seem to overlap.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid race condition in handling the list's selection change.

```
list.addListener("changeSelection",function(event)
{
  switch(event.getData()[0].getModel().classname)
  {
    case "test.obj1":
      this.stack.setSelection([this.renderedForm1]);
      this.form1Controller.setModel(this.listController.getSelection().getItem(0));
      break;
    case "test.obj2":
      this.stack.setSelection([this.renderedForm2]);
      this.form2Controller.setModel(this.listController.getSelection().getItem(0));
      break;
    default:
      this.stack.setSelection([]);
  }
}, this);
```

For future questions I suggest you to expand your questions. For this question the scenario when you switch from instance of `test.obj1` to `test.obj2` and back in the list, which causes the overlap would save time of an answerer.